# Apple validating receipt-data 21002 error - PHP backend & React Native

Tags: php, react-native, curl, in-app-purchase

I am using react-native-iap to make subscriptions to the app store. I am trying to validate the receipts and I get error 210002. I send from react native fetch function the receipt data and handle it in the php backend like this...

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
```

Then in my function to get the receipt I do this...

```
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  $curl_post_data = array(
          'receipt-data' => $request->receipt,
          'password' => $password
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  ...
```

I have tried wrapping the `$request->receipt` in `json_encode()`.

I have looked at what I believe is every Stack Overflow answer about this and I cannot seem to get it right.

When I print what the receipt I am getting from fetch it is this...

```
[29-Oct-2019 00:45:29 UTC] stdClass Object
(
    [transactionReceipt] => 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
    [originalTransactionIdentifierIOS] => (originaltransactionId)
    [transactionDate] => (transactionseconds)
    [originalTransactionDateIOS] => (originaltransactionseconds)
    [productId] => (productId)
    [transactionId] => (transactionId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was sending the entire transaction receipt object, instead of the 'transactionReceipt' property of the object that was sent via fetch. So I just needed to change this...

```
$curl_post_data = array(
          'receipt-data' => $request->receipt,
          'password' => $password
  );
```

to this...

```
$curl_post_data = array(
          'receipt-data' => $request->receipt->transactionReceipt,
          'password' => $password
  );
```